# How to do a line integral visually in version 10 or later

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In version 10, Mathematica introduces some **Region** functions, which allow us to do integrals very visually. We can do this even if we don't know any *Mathematica* syntax and it can help me show others that don't use this software. I can do any integral use these two steps:

- Plot the function, show the region to integral

  ```
  ContourPlot[{E^x == y, y == 2, x == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
  ```

[image]

- Make an `ImplicitRegion` to integral and do calculation

  ```
  region = ImplicitRegion[Reduce[{y > E^x, x > 0, y < 2}], {x, y}];
  NIntegrate[E^(x y)/(y^y - 1), Element[{x, y}, region]]
  ```

Additionally, we can do it in textbook form directly like:

[image]

This is very intuitive to show.

---

### Question

How can we use this ***region feature*** do line integrals? Such as the vector field is `{y, x}`. The region is `RegionUnion[Circle[{0,0},1,{0,45°}],Line[{{0,0},{1,0}}]]` The move direction is from $O\to A\to B$ as follows:

```
Show[VectorPlot[{y, x}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], 
 Graphics[{Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, 45°}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Style[Text["A", {.9, -.1}], 20, Red], 
   Style[Text["B", {Sqrt[2]/2, .8}], 20, Red]}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  Axes -> True, Frame -> False, Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

As I know, the result is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Or caculate the line integral in a close path, region is `RegionUnion[Circle[{0,0},1,{0,45°}],Line[{{0,0},{1,0}}],Line[{{Sqrt[2]/2,Sqrt[2]/2},{0,0}}]]`,its direction is from $O\to A\to B\to O$:

```
Show[VectorPlot[{y, x}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], 
 Graphics[{Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, 45 °}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Arrow[{{Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[2]/2}, {0, 0}}], 
   Style[Text["A", {.9, -.1}], 20, Red], 
   Style[Text["B", {Sqrt[2]/2, .8}], 20, Red]}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  Axes -> True, Frame -> False, Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

As I know, the result is $0$. Of course, this vector field `{y,x}` is very simple so that you can see the result just by a glance, but this is just an example. I want know the general method.

Comment: The word "visually" and using `*Region*` functions mean different things to me, but one obstacle to the latter is that regions are not oriented. E.g., the mesh elements in `DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi/4}], Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}]]]` do not have a consistent orientation. A solution will have to address orientation, as well as calculating tangents for the variety of possible regions and, if desired, recursive refinement of the mesh for whatever integration rules one wants. Not to mention singularity handling or other features of `NIntegrate`. A very big project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way could be defining a proper parameter along the path.

Let's say you know the points on the path or equation of the path (`Piecewise` maybe).

```
pts = Join[{#, 0.} & /@ Range[0., 0.9, 0.1], {Cos[#], Sin[#]} & /@ Range[0., Pi/4, Pi/60],
           # {Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4]} & /@ Range[.9, 0.0, -0.1]];
```

Define the path as a function of a single parameter

```
x[t_] = Interpolation[pts[[All, 1]]][t]
y[t_] = Interpolation[pts[[All, 2]]][t]
tmax = Length[pts]
```

According to this parameterisation

> \begin{array}{ll}
> &t=1,tmax & O \\
> &t=11  & A \\
> &t=26 & B
> \end{array}

You can define individual sections as well. Now define the vector field and do the integration ($\int \vec{v}.\vec{dl}$)

```
vec[t_] = {y[t], x[t]}
dl[t_] = {D[x[t], t], D[y[t], t]}; (*Differential path element*)


NIntegrate[vec[t].dl[t], {t, 1, 26}] (*OAB*)
NIntegrate[vec[t].dl[t], {t, 26, tmax}](*BO*)
NIntegrate[vec[t].dl[t], {t, 1, tmax}](*OABO*)
```

> 0.5
>
> -0.5
>
> $-4.92228 \times 10^{-17}$

```
Show[VectorPlot[{y, x}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}], 
Graphics[{Table[{Blue, Arrow[{{x[t], y[t]}, {x[t + 1], y[t + 1]}}], 
Red, Arrow[{{x[t], y[t]}, {x[t], y[t]} + 0.2 vec[t]}]}, {t, 1, tmax - 1, 1}], 
Table[Text[Style[t, 18, Bold], {x[t], y[t]}], {t, {1, 11, 26}}]}]]
```

[image]

### parameterisation [t]

Here the parameter `t` is just the serial number of the points along the path. You can provide more points for better interpolation result in case of a curvy path. You can check it by

```
Graphics[{Gray, Arrowheads[{0, .05, .05, .05, 0.05}], Arrow[pts], 
          Black, Table[Text[t, {x[t], y[t]}], {t, tmax}]}]
```

[image]

316 is actually overlapping 1 and 36.

Comment: What's meaning the `dl`？And why use `vec[t].dl[t]`?As I konw the integral result is 0.5 but not 9.5?

Comment: Now it is the correct one (with explanation) :)

Comment: Wow,you did it. :)Can you show how do you get that $26$ or $11$?And would you think the region feature introduced in v10.0 would be helpful?

Comment: I am not quite sure about Region. In principle, you can define the path as a region with a very tiny width  and use the surface integration. I will check it later.

Comment: In this case,the region is `RegionUnion[Circle[{0,0},1,{0,45°}],
Line[{{0,0},{1,0}}]]`