# How to calculate the surface integral of a vector field?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus

Suppose the oriented surface is described as, the outside of an upper hemisphere $S:x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ inside the cylinder $x^2-x+y^2=0$

[image]

The vector field is : ${\vec F}=<x^2,y^2,z^2>$

[image]

How to calculate the surface integral of the vector field:
$$\iint\limits_{S^+} \vec F\cdot \vec n {\rm d}S $$

[image]

Is it the same thing to:

$$\iint\limits_{S^+}x^2{\rm d}y{\rm d}z+y^2{\rm d}x{\rm d}z+z^2{\rm d}x{\rm d}y$$

There is [another post here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83681/how-can-i-evaluate-surface-integral-in-mathematica) with an answer by@MichaelE2 for the cases when the surface is easily described in parametric form. How to handle this case?

Comment: Note that `{x, y, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}` is one parameterization of the upper hemisphere.  There's another in spherical coordinates, and so forth.

Comment: For this case, does that mean `S = {{x, y, z} -> {Cos[u] v/2 +1/2, Sin[u] v/2, Sqrt[ 1 - (Cos[u] v/2 +1/2)^2 - (Sin[u] v/2)^2]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0,  1}};
F = {x^2, y^2, z^2};`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try using [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion) and [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate):

```
region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 && x^2 - x + y^2 <= 0 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}];

Integrate[#, {x,y,z} ∈ region]& /@ ({x^2, y^2, z^2} . {x, y, z})

(* 38/105 + (5 π)/32 *)
```

Note that the normal vector is just `{x, y, z}` for a unit sphere. I also map [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) over the summands to make things easier for [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate).

Comment: Heck... this is far simpler than the traditional integration technique I was working on.  (+1)

Comment: How about [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129662/21532)?Actually I don't very content with the current solution.

Comment: One more question: why `Integrate[#, {x, y, z}∈ ImplicitRegion[ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 && x^2 - x + y^2 <= 0 && z >= 0, {x, y, 
      z}]] &@({x^2, y^2, z^2}.{x, y, z})` is slower than the code in the answer? there is only one `/` difference @yode @CarlWoll

Comment: `Integrate[x^3+y^3+z^3, {x,y,z} ∈ region]` is harder for Integrate than doing `Integrate[x^3, {x, y, z} ∈ region] + Integrate[y^3, {x, y, z} ∈ region] + Integrate[z^3, {x, y, z} ∈ region]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll When I rewrite the direction vector of your surface to another equivalent form, the result is different from yours. Why can't we use `{-(x/Sqrt[-x^2 - y^2 + 1]), -(y/Sqrt[-x^2 - y^2 + 1]), 1}` instead of `{x, y, z}` : 
 `Integrate[#, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
    region] & /@ ({region = 
     ImplicitRegion[
      x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 && x^2 - x + y^2 <= 0 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}];
    
    Integrate[#, {x, y, z} \[Element] region] & /@ ({x^2, y^2, 
        z^2}.{x, y, z}), y^2, 
    z^2}.{-(x/Sqrt[-x^2 - y^2 + 1]), -(y/Sqrt[-x^2 - y^2 + 1]), 1})`

Comment: @Ordinaryusers68 The direction vector should have unit norm. `{x, y, z}` has unit norm on the unit sphere. Your direction vector does not have unit norm.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thank you very much. I can't get the correct result when I use your method to solve a surface integral. I'm very confused. Could you please answer [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226708/how-to-calculate-this-surface-integral)?

Comment: @CarlWoll I'm sorry I'm still asking you. When I use the following example in your mind, after about two minutes of running, I get a mixed integral sign wrong answer. I want to know what's wrong?  `region = ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 4 && x^2 - x + y^2 <= 0 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}];

Integrate[#, {x, y, z} \[Element] region] & /@ ({x^2, y^2, z^2}.{x/2, 
    y/2, z/2})`

Answer (score 8):

With the new-in-*13.3* `SurfaceIntegrate`:

```
preg = 
  ParametricRegion[{u, v, Sqrt[1 - u^2 - v^2]}, 
                   {{u, 0, 1}, {v, -Sqrt[u - u^2], Sqrt[u - u^2]}}];

SurfaceIntegrate[{x^2, y^2, z^2}, {x, y, z} ∈ preg]
(* 38/105 + (5 π)/32 *)
```

[image]

Sadly the following doesn't work for the moment:

```
SurfaceIntegrate[{x^2, y^2, z^2}, {x, y, z} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 && x^2 - x + y^2 <= 0 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}]]
(* Input returned. *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to illustrate use of **MichaelE2's** [DoubleContourIntegral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83797/1997):

```
DoubleContourIntegral[{x^2, y^2, 
  z^2}, {({x, y, z} -> {u, v, Sqrt[1 - u^2 - v^2]}), {u, 0, 
   1}, {v, -Sqrt[u - u^2], Sqrt[u - u^2]}}]
```

yields:
38/105 + (5 π)/32

Note the limits of integration.

Comment: Thank you. I use: `S = {{x, y, z} -> {Cos[v] u/2 + 1/2, Sin[v] u/2, Sqrt[1 - (Cos[v] u/2 + 1/2)^2 - (Sin[v] u/2)^2]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}};F = {x^2, y^2, z^2}; \[DoubleContourIntegral]F \[DifferentialD]S` but is very slow.

Comment: Is it possible to convert it into the sum of three double integrals on the projections of the oriented surface to $xoy$,$yoz$ and $xoz$ axis planes?

Comment: ·Integrate[ 1 - x^2 - y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[x - x^2], Sqrt[x - x^2]}]+Integrate[
 1 - z^2 - y^2, {z, 0, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[z^2 - z^4], Sqrt[z^2 - z^4]}]· is the answer. thanks